# Why is docChange getting called twice after delete on document?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a collection in firestore. I am listening for changes on node backend. Now when I receive change, then I process the data and delete the Firestore document associated with the change. When I call delete, I once again get the same change in the listener and I end up process the data once again.

I searched over internet and could not find any solution for the issue.

```
let doc_form_reponse = db.collection(CONSTANTS.FIREBASE.COLLECTIONS.SUBMISSIONS);
let qref1 = doc_form_reponse.where('context', '==', 'someContext').where('processed', '==', false);
let observer_form_response = qref1.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
    docSnapshot.docChanges().forEach(docChange => {
        let doc = docChange.doc;
        // save data to Mongo Db
        var survey = Surveyresponse({
            resp: docChange.doc.data().response,
            metadata: JSON.stringify(docChange.doc.data().metadata)
        });

        survey.save(function (err, resp) {
            if (err) return console.error(err)
            else {
                console.log(doc.id," deleted from firebase");
                doc.ref.delete();
            }

        })
    })
    // ...
}, err => {
    console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```

After calling doc.ref.delete() once a change is received and once again a DB entry is getting made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listeners on queries in Cloud Firestore will trigger every time the result set for the query changes.  So, if you delete a document that you got from a query, your listener will trigger again to reflect that change.  This is normal behavior, and there is no way around it.  If you don't want to process deletions from the result set, then you will have to check the type of the document change in your listener, [as described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).  Your `docChange` has a type parameter that indicates what's different in the change than the previous snapshot.